# Should (summation-method) be a synonym of (summation)?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Not so long ago [the tag-synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/synonyms) [summation-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation-method) $\to$ [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) has been suggested. I wonder whether this is the best choice of synonym.

Both from the questions currently tagged with this tag and from the meaning of the phrase *summation method* which I am familiar with (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series)) these two tags are very different. The tag [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) is for finite sums. The phrases *summation method* or *[summability method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summability_methods)* are used for various approaches which assign some kind of sum even to series which are divergent in the usual sense.

We have two already existing tags where this meaning might fit. The [tag excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/44918/revisions) for [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) currently says that this tag is for *"questions on whether certain series diverge, and how to deal with divergent series using summation methods such as Ramanujan summation and others."* This is the only tag I know of where tag-info explicitly mentions summation methods. I have also seen the tag [regularization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularization) used for questions of this type. However, this does not agree with the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1275153/revisions) and [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1275154/revisions).

The synonym was also mentioned in the [Tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23314512#23314512).

> What should we do with the above synonym suggestion? Would [summation-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation-method) $\to$ [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) be a better choice?

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the tag ([tag:divergent-series]) was mentioned [in this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20959/how-should-questions-about-deciding-convergence-divergence-of-a-series-be-tagged), too.

Comment: The suggested synonym I mentioned is not in the [list of tag synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) at the moment. So it has either been downvoted or removed by a moderator.